# Youtube Content Partner API access problems

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm having problem with the youtube partner api.

I have written an application that correctly establishes an oauth connection between myself and previously authorised Content Manager page and can view my associated channels, create and manage assets etc.

I have a colleague from a different organisation with a separate content manager account that manages around 20 separate channels.  They can use the app to successfully complete the oauth flow.  However when we try and iterate their channel listings they receive the following error:

```
Google_Service_Exception: { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "youtube.common", "reason": "cmsUserAccountNotFound", "message": "The CMS user is not allowed to act on behalf of the specified content owner." } ], "code": 403, "message": "The CMS user is not allowed to act on behalf of the specified content owner." }
```

If they add my account as an administrator of the Content Manager account, I can however see their pages. They have permission to manage all pages under the account (and are the administrator)

My question is:

1. Is this because they don't have permission to use the API (although they have authorised the App that has requested permissions)?
2. If we create a service account and add it to their Content Manager account and change the oauth flow to this, will this resolve the issue?
3. ...Or is there something else I'm missing?

Many thanks in advance for advice.